# Is there any way to show what a specific custom overloaded operator does?

Tags: c#, overloading, summarization

Is there any way to give an equivalent of a method summary to an overloaded operator?

i.e. I have the following object with an overloaded + operator and a custom method:

```
CustomObject objectA = new CustomObject();
CustomObject objectB = new CustomObject();

objectA.MyInt = 10;
objectA.MyString = "hello"; 

objectB.MyInt = 55;
objectB.MyString = "apple";

objectA.CustomMethod(34);

objectA += objectB;
```

If this object was in a library and I was using it, I could mouse over the custom method to see a summary written by the creator to see what the method does. Is there a similar way to see the effect of the overloaded operator?

In this example you don't know what it will do with the value or the string. Sum and Append? Max and Replace? Multiply and Ignore?

Comment: Insert (type) `///` above your method, it will add summary block (If you're using  Visual Studio).

Comment: This comment is not to answer the question, but to offer an opinion:  **if it is not absolutely clear from the context what an overloaded operator does then do not overload the operator**.  People get it into their heads that they want to make "cute" overloads where Customer plus Product equals PurchaseOrder and it makes for code that is impossible to understand. Overload `+` for things like complex numbers, vectors, and other mathematical objects that have a clear, well-defined addition operator.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, this is more for convenience. A method needs to give a success or fail and also pass back any error messages from exceptions. The class in this case is a Result class that needs to add multiple database storage results together. Essentially it needs to be false if any of the added Results are false but also concatenate any returned error messages. Essentially overloading the operator just means the person writing the manager doesn't need to do these checks for every call to the database.

Comment: I would consider overloading the operation of summation to mean "accumulate error information in an error buffer" to be a very bad programming practice in C#. It sounds like you are trying to reinvent the error monad; why not just use the error monad? Or for that matter, just use `Task<T>`, since it is a superset of the behaviours of the error monad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following code which demonstrates the use of the `/// <summary></summary>` tag:

```
public class Test
{
    /// <summary>Returns a new Test with X set to the sum of lhs.X and rhs.X</summary>
    public static Test operator+ (Test lhs, Test rhs)
    {
        return new Test {X = lhs.X + rhs.X};
    }

    public int X;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test a = new Test {X = 1};
        Test b = new Test {X = 2};
        Test c = a + b;
    }
}
```

If you hover over the `+` in the line `Test c = a + b;`, the tooltip will say:

> Returns a new Test with X set to the sum of lhs.X and rhs.X

(I feel sure that there should be a duplicate question for this, but I had a search and I couldn't find one specific to operator overloads.)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried summary and it hadn't seemed to work. I was very likely hovering over the wrong part as it does indeed look to work fine. Thank you!